# Hey guys, how I can write this python code in R to perform exact operation?

Tags: python, r

```py
from itertools import combinations, permutations
group = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
comb = permutations([0, 1, 2, 3], 2)
for i in list(comb):
    x1 = group[i[0]]
    x2 = group[i[1]] 
    print(x1, x2)
```

Comment: although @akrun has been kind enough to translate your code for you, I'm going to suggest that this is *not* a good question for Stack Overflow - you should try to identify a *specific* part of the problem you're trying to solve rather than asking (however politely) strangers to please translate your code for you ...

Answer (score 2):

We need `permutations`

```
gtools::permutations(4, 2, letters[1:4])
```

-output

```
 [,1] [,2]
 [1,] "a"  "b" 
 [2,] "a"  "c" 
 [3,] "a"  "d" 
 [4,] "b"  "a" 
 [5,] "b"  "c" 
 [6,] "b"  "d" 
 [7,] "c"  "a" 
 [8,] "c"  "b" 
 [9,] "c"  "d" 
[10,] "d"  "a" 
[11,] "d"  "b" 
[12,] "d"  "c"
```

---

If we need a loop that matches with `python` code (indexing in `R` starts from 1)

```
group <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
comb <- gtools::permutations(4, 2, seq_along(group))
for(i in seq_len(nrow(comb))) {
    x1 <- group[comb[i, 1]]
    x2 <- group[comb[i, 2]]
    cat(paste(x1, x2), "\n")
}
```

-output

```
a b 
a c 
a d 
b a 
b c 
b d 
c a 
c b 
c d 
d a 
d b 
d c
```

-testing with OP's python code

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to use x1 and x2 in the other parts of the code also.
I would highly appreciate if you could write this complete python code in R (including loop)

Comment: @Alok The output is a `matrix` and the columns are 'x1', and 'x2'.  If you want to loop over the `matrix` to do something, you can use `m1 <- gtools::permutations(4, 2, letters[1:4]); apply(m1, MARGIN = 1, FUN = yourfunction)` or `for(i in seq_len(nrow(m1))) yourfun(m1[i,1], m1[i,2])`

Comment: I see. To make my question a bit more clear, here are my thoughts,
suppose I have the following R code snippet.

write.table(read.csv("res_paired_temp_LFC.csv", sep=","), file="a_vs_b.tab", sep="\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)

I am saving the final output as a table called (a_vs_b.tab). And this has to repeat multiple times. Now, it is important to me to change the name of the table automatically (eg., a_vs_c.tab). This is why I wanted to write x1 on the place of "a" and x2 on the place of "b". Any suggestions? let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: @Alok I updated the solution (if you check my update with a `for` loop).  Having said that you may not even need to go through the same procedure that you adopted in python and use it in R.  Each languages have different strengths and weakness.  If I were you, I make use of the strength in a particular language instead of trying to emulate line-by-line code written in another language